# Can I get vite to reload the browser on every html change?

Tags: vite

I'm using vite to serve a legacy AngularJS project because I'm a maniac.  Hot reload works for the bundled .js and index html, but it's trying to use HMR for component html changes which isn't working.  I'd be happy to trigger a full page reload for component html changes.

When a component html changes, I get a message on the vite console acknowledging it, but only the index.html triggers a full reload.  I figure this has to be configurable, but it's the opposite of what most people want so it's hard to find out how to pull this off (if it's possible).

`[server] 10:01:42 AM [vite] page reload app/components/Funding/FundingEditor/FundingEditor.html`

The above does not trigger a full page reload, but I wish it did.

`[server] 10:02:05 AM [vite] page reload index.html`

The above does trigger a full page reload, cool.

Is there a way to configure vite to get the full page to reload on component html changes as well?